# boost::asio::write() VS socket->write_some()

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to learn `boost::asi`o and I have some problems with `boost::asio::write()`, `socket->write_some()`. From what I read until now I learn that `boost::asio::write` assure that all data was transfer while `socket->write` doesn't do that because is using `send` from OS and this doesn't guarantee full transmission.

Here is a part of my `client/server` app.

server

```
void server::session(socket_ptr sock)
{
char data[MAX_SIZE] = {};
bool flag = false;
sprintf(data,"On the server are %d users.",user_vector.size());

//boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(data, strlen(data)));
sock->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, strlen(data)));

cleanMemory(data,strlen(data));
try
{
    for (;;)
    {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
        //boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(data,strlen(data)));
        cout << std::endl << data;
        cleanMemory(data, strlen(data));
        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            std::vector<user_detail>::iterator it = user_vector.begin();
            for (; it!= user_vector.end();)
            {
                std::pair<socket_ptr, int> user = *it;
                if (user.first == sock)
                {
                    cout << "User " << user.second << " leave server." << std::endl;
                    cout << std::endl << "Connection has been closed." << std::endl;
                    it = user_vector.erase(it);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    ++it;
            }
            if (flag)
                break;
        }
    }
}
catch (const std::exception&e) {
    std::cerr << "Error in threead : " << e.what() << endl;
}
}
```

client

```
size_t length = s.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf,100)); //OK DATA RECEVIED
    //boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(buf, 100));//FAIL TO RECEIVE DATA
    cout.write(buf,strlen(buf));
```

The problem is on the client side. If I use:

```
size_t length = s.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf,100));
```

Works ok and data is recevide but if i use:

```
boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(buf, 100));
```

Data is lost.

**Question:**

1. If the **server** sends data, for example using `boost::asio::write` **client** need to use `boost::asio::read` or can also use `socket.read_some()`?
2. What is more exactly connection between `boost::Asio::read` and `socket->read_some`, and why does this work only if i use `s.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf,100));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::asio::read()` will read until

a) all 100 bytes has been read, or

b) there is an error, or

c) there is an end-of-stream condition.

It is a compound operation. One of the effects of that is that it can both return an error and have read some data.

For example, if 50 bytes are read and then the stream enters an eof condition, the `bytes_transferred` will be 50 and the error_code returned will indicate end of file.

With a compound operation it's important to check the bytes_transferred before you check the error.